# inferring property t from the existence of property p without sub-property axiom

Tags: owl, ontology

Presume you have a property p.
How can I model the following problem with OWL2 (i'm talking solely about object properties):

I want to make property t inferable from the existence of an instance of property p, without using the sub-property axiom. Or: when there is a triple like `A p B` -> I want to infer the following triple `A t B`, but there soul'd be no `p rdfs:subpropertyOf+ t` in my ontology (also no owl:equivalentProperty as well!).

I can't use the subproperty axiom since this would in fact mean to hijack a foreign ontology. And i can't replace these properties with my own as well , since they are well established.
I know, i can do this for property paths with more than one property by using the property-chain axiom. But since this axiom needs at least two properties i'm stuck with this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you would "hijack" a foreign ontology by using sub-property. Just import the ontology and augment it with yours, isn't that the most common practice? Or maybe you want to use it without creating dependency?

Comment: I agree with Ivo, I don't think hijacking is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try with

```
some p A subClassOf some r A
```

Any time an individual has a r-filler of type A, it will also be inferred to have a p-filler of type A. Having the same individuals for both requires a more finessed approach though.

However I think a subproperty axiom is the best solution.

Comment: As you mentioned, that won't lead to the relationship of the same individuals that are related by `t` as he asked for. Either rules or the subPropertyOf axiom, else it's not possible in OWL as it is free of variables.